# Escalated predefined ssh scripts to remote computer implemetation

Tags: ssh, security, remote, suid

The problem is that I want to run certain ssh commands (Or scripts) from computerA to computerB without using a password.

Examples:

```
ssh apple@computerB 'poweroff'
ssh apple@computerB "killall firefox; systemctl enable apache; firefox"
ssh apple@computerB < superscript.txt
```

I also want to do this as secure as I can get it. I should not be able to ssh to computerB if I simply open up a terminal. And obviously not be able to edit the scripts/programs and run them afterwards.

I was thinking about using SUID and a different user with ssh keys to access the computer but there are security concerns regarding SUID and interpreted scripts.

Do anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Probably better to have keys with force-commands specified.  See https://ctrlnotes.com/restrict-a-user-to-ssh-forced-command/ for examples.

Comment: That's excellent. Thank you

Comment: I've adapted that into an answer you might like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having SUID programs on the SSH host, it's better to connect as a user with the required privileges, but to bind a specific command to that key.

We do that in the target user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.  For example,

```
command="poweroff" ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIJQwKcn2AJxNpuzRM/SfJLn0UEXCMmAmI2Xdqeng4nB9 saft@home
```

If we want to use one of several commands, we can use a script that interprets `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` appropriately:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
  poweroff)
    exec poweroff
    ;;
  firefox)
    killall firefox; systemctl enable apache; exec firefox
    ;;
  *)
    printf '%s\n' >&2 \
        "Unrecognised command `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND'" \
        'Valid commands are:' \
        ' * poweroff' \
        ' * firefox'
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```